# Отображение текста на FloatingActionButton

Tags: android

Можно вывести на FloatingActionButton (Fab) текст/число? У меня лента новостей и хочу сделать вывод нумерац страницы. Можно поверх фаба текс с привязкой к нему?

Comment: такое нельзя сделать(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаете класс `TextDrawable.java` и используете для своих целей:

```
fab.setImageDrawable(new TextDrawable("2", ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.BLACK), 32.f, TextDrawable.VerticalAlignment.BASELINE));
```

`TextDrawable`:

```
public class TextDrawable extends Drawable {

    protected final Paint textPaint;
    protected ColorStateList color;
    protected String text;
    protected int iHeight;
    protected int iWidth;
    protected int measuredWidth, measuredHeight;
    private float ascent;
    private VerticalAlignment verticalAlignment;

    public TextDrawable(String text, ColorStateList color, float textSize, VerticalAlignment verticalAlignment) {
        textPaint = new Paint();
        this.text = text;
        initPaint();
        this.textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
        measureSize();
        setBounds(0, 0, iWidth, iHeight);
        this.color = color;
        textPaint.setColor(color.getDefaultColor());
        this.verticalAlignment = verticalAlignment;
    }

    private void initPaint() {
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    }

    public void setColor(ColorStateList colorStateList) {
        if (this.color == null || !this.color.equals(colorStateList)) {
            this.color = colorStateList;
            invalidateSelf();
        }
    }

    protected void measureSize() {
        ascent = -textPaint.ascent();
        iWidth = (int) (0.5f + textPaint.measureText(text));
        iHeight = (int) (0.5f + textPaint.descent() + ascent);
        measuredWidth = iWidth;
        measuredHeight = iHeight;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        final Rect bounds = getBounds();
        int stack = canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(bounds.left, bounds.top);
        if (text != null && !text.isEmpty()) {
            final float x = bounds.width() >= iWidth ? bounds.centerX() : iWidth * 0.5f;
            float y = 0;
            switch (verticalAlignment) {
                case BASELINE:
                    y = (bounds.height() - iHeight) * 0.5f + ascent;
                    break;
                case TOP:
                    y = bounds.height();
                    break;
                case BOTTOM:
                    y = bounds.height();
                    break;
            }
            canvas.drawText(text, x, y, textPaint);
        }
        canvas.restoreToCount(stack);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        if (textPaint.getAlpha() != alpha) {
            textPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
            invalidateSelf();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        if (textPaint.getColorFilter() == null || !textPaint.getColorFilter().equals(cf)) {
            textPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
            invalidateSelf();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }

    public enum VerticalAlignment {
        TOP, BOTTOM, BASELINE
    }
}
```

результат: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо огромное